# Php form retaining input about file upload if captcha fails

Tags: php, captcha, image-uploading

I would to know how to retain information entered for photo upload in php form if either captcha or invalid entry occurs.  All other fields retain their input, with the exception of upload path, i.e. person enters "C:\Users\inc\Desktop\3.png" and path is lost if either occurs during form submission (...php5#error)

```
<div class="photo">
  <li class='field_block' id='field_35_div'>
    <div class='col_label'>
      <label class='form_field'>Photo 1</label>
      <label class='form_required' >&nbsp;</label>
    </div>
    <div class='col_field'>
      <input type="file" name="field_35"  id="field_35" value="" class='text_box1' onchange="fmgHandler.check_upload(this);">
      <div id='field_35_tip' class='instruction'></div>
    </div>
```

I tried adding echo, but this does not work.

Comment: when you are submitting the values and checking the fields, do you put the default values from POST into the form fields if input is invalid?

Comment: If I understand correctly, no.  Fields are blanks until the visitor fills in them in.  The only field I'm having the problem with is upload....

Answer (score 2):

File fields cannot be pre-populated. And you probably don't want the user to have to upload the file every time again and again anyway, as that may potentially take a long time.

Save the file somewhere on your server and remember either in the session or in a hidden input field which file it was. Display something like *"file uploaded"* next to the file selector. If the user choses to upload another file, overwrite the previously uploaded file, otherwise use the previously uploaded file.

Comment: Sorry, don't follow your suggestion.  As you said, I do not want the user to have to upload files each time, especially if they make an error with the captcha.  The issue is to have the input saved, i.e. C:\Users\inc\Desktop\3.png" and placed back in the upload field if an error occurs so they do need to upload - select images again.

Comment: No, you don't want to put "C:\Users\inc\Desktop\3.png" back into the file upload field. a) that's not possible and b) let's pretend it's a 50 MB file which took 10 minutes to upload the first time around. You don't want your user to have to do that again. Also, you already have the file on the server. Keep it on the server (as if the form submission was successful) and just tell the user "OK, I have your file, now I only need you to fill out the rest of the form correctly."

Comment: Thanks.  I'm new at this, any input is helpful.  I gave the form a try, selecting the images, leaving required field blank.  Received the error message, fill in this field, did so, submit again.  The files where not uploaded, just input text.  Not sure how to handle this.  If you have any suggestions, would be greatly appreciated